# why nvidia driver requires us to exit X before installation?

Tags: drivers

I am successfully able to install NVIDIA driver in windows from GUI. But in linux it requires to exit the X. Why it is so? Why driver isntallation and X cannot go parallel ?

Answer (score 0):

The NVIDIA driver is actually becomes part of the X server, and rewrites the configuration to work.   Its possible that NVIDIA could rewrite it to work, but its probably more work then they are willing to put in - I guess the argument being if someone does not know how to install it from the command line they should just use a distro which supports it out the box.

**Additional Information (to answer @grawity)**

[Here](http://www.x.org/wiki/NVIDIAProprietaryDriver/) is a link from the X.org site evidencing that the nvidia driver hooks
itself into the kernel (ie before start of X).  Further information is in the "KERNEL INTERFACES" explanation from nvidia, [here](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/1.0-7174/README.txt) - which states "The NVIDIA kernel module has a kernel interface layer which must be
compiled specifically for the configuration and version of the kernel
you are running.  NVIDIA distributes the source code to this kernel
interface layer, as well as a precompiled version for many of the kernels
distributed by some popular distributions." before going into further detail.  Also see the answer to the question on this page "I just upgraded my kernel, and now the NVIDIA kernel module will not load.  What is wrong", to which NVIDIA answer

```
"
A: The kernel interface layer of the NVIDIA kernel module must be
   compiled specifically for the configuration and version of your kernel.
   If you upgrade your kernel, then the simplest solution is to reinstall
   the driver.
```

ADVANCED: You can install the NVIDIA kernel module for a non 
   running kernel (for example: in the situation where you just built
   and installed a new kernel, but have not rebooted yet) with a command
   line such as this:

```
sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-1.0-7174-pkg1.run --kernel-name='KERNEL_NAME'
```

Where 'KERNEL_NAME' is what `uname -r` would report if the target
   kernel were running."

Also, it should be pointed out that the architecture of the X Window system is fundamentally different to the "Microsoft" Window modelling system, and NVIDIA are actually providing a version of the X Server.  For an architectural overview, look [here](http://linuxfreak.org/window-system2.html).

Comment: ...only in the same way that the Windows nVidia driver becomes part of the Windows kernel. That is, not at all.

Comment: @grawity - please look at my expanded answer.  I'd really appreciate it if you would undo your down mod or provide a more compelling answer or rebuttal.